# Show clear names instead of anonymous names in Office 365 Report- PowerShell or Graph

Tags: powershell, microsoft-office-365, microsoft-graph

Microsoft has made anonymous display of user-names as default in Office 365 and also enforced it from August 31, 2021. I found a way to overcome it from Admin Portal. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/troubleshoot/miscellaneous/reports-show-anonymous-user-name

I want to update this setting using PowerShell or Graph. As far as I have checked, there is no method found. Has anyone found any solution for it.

This link talks about it but it is two years old: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/anonymous-reporting-in-office-365/65e9e96f-fb04-4563-9961-e56a1fa8181d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beginning on June 23, 2022, an API will gradually become available to all environments for global admins to change this setting without needing to visit the Microsoft 365 admin center. The API details are below:

The URL is https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/admin/reportSettings

Kind regards,

Clark

Answer (score 0):

I have actually resolved this by following the below link. I missed answering here.

https://o365reports.com/2021/09/07/microsoft-365-reports-show-anonymous-user-names-instead-of-actual-user-names/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).